# Why the sum of probability must $\leq$ the probability of union?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, statistics

$P$ is a finite additive probability. $\{A_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ are a countable sequence of disjoint events. Why $\sum_{j=1}^\infty P(A_j)\leq P(\cup_{j=1}^\infty A_j)??$

A tentative proof (might need to involve prove by contradiction):

$\sum_{j=1}^nP(A_j)=P(\cup_1^n A_j)\leq P(\cup_{j=1}^\infty A_j)$.

But I stuck here and  don't know how to link $\sum_{j=1}^nP(A_j)$ with $\sum_{j=1}^\infty P(A_j)$

Comment: This is a result known as union bound or Boole’s inequality. A proof can be found in any probability text

Comment: Presumably the sets $A_j$ are pairwise disjoint, right?

Comment: @AndrewZhang Boole's inequality is the other way around, and it's for a countably additive probability.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Yes it is a sequence of disjoint event

Comment: Why would you ne3ed a proof by contradiction. You already have that $\sum^N_{j=1}P(A_j)=P(\cup^N_{j-1}A_j)$ and since $\cup^N_{j=1}A_j\subset \bigcup_nA_n$, $\sum^n_{n=1}P(A_j)\leq P(\bigcup_nA_n)$. The conclusion then follows by letting $N\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: @OliverDíaz Are you sure we can always set $"N\to\infty"$? What is the rational behind this? Is this by induction? I was told that math induction not always hold with countable infinite. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @HighGPA: sure, $P$ is nonnegative, then the sequence $s_N=\sum^N_{j=1}P[A_j]$ is bounded and nondecreasing. Thus $s_N$ converges.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks! I think I understand it now